# GPUImage RawDataInput and RawDataOutput rotates image

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to use GPUImage rawInput and rawOutput to do some custom stuff, but somehow my output is rotated.

I'm setting my GPUImageVideoCamera like this:

```
self.videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
self.videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
self.videoCamera.runBenchmark = YES;
```

And then just this.

```
CGSize rawSize = CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0 );
GPUImageRawDataOutput *rawOutput = [[GPUImageRawDataOutput alloc] initWithImageSize:rawSize resultsInBGRAFormat:YES];
GPUImageRawDataInput __block *rawInput = [[GPUImageRawDataInput alloc] initWithBytes:[rawOutput rawBytesForImage] size:rawSize];;

__weak GPUImageRawDataOutput *weakRawOutput = rawOutput;
[rawOutput setNewFrameAvailableBlock:^{
    [weakRawOutput rawBytesForImage];        
    [rawInput updateDataFromBytes:[weakRawOutput rawBytesForImage] size:rawSize];
    [rawInput processData];
}];
```

and of course

```
[self.videoCamera addTarget:rawOutput];
[rawInput addTarget:self.cameraView];
[self.videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

This is what i get

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yo19o7ryagk58le/2013-12-05%2018.02.56.png

Any ideas how to PROPERLY handle this?

---

EDIT:

I just found out, that putting sepia filter before rawOutput corrects rotation, but grayScale filter doesn't ...